# How to implement pagination with kotlin flows

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I am new to kotlin flows. I am following [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer) to set up the UI layer in Android.

This is my UI stateFlow

```
private val _teamsUiState = MutableStateFlow(TeamsUiState())
val teamsUiState: StateFlow<TeamsUiState> = _teamsUiState.asStateFlow()
```

This is my TeamsUiState data class:

```
data class TeamsUiState(
    val teamItems: ArrayList<Team> = ArrayList(),
    val error: String? = null
)
```

I am fetching the response from the API on a coroutine and handling it like this

```
fetchTeamsJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            fetchTeamsJob?.cancel()
            response.collectLatest {
                when (it) {
                    is Result.Success -> {
                        it.data?.payload?.let { payload ->
                            if (payload.teams != null) {
                                _teamsUiState.update { teamsState ->
                                    // Problem here
                                    teamsState.copy(teamItems = ArrayList(payload.teams))
                                }
                            }
                            val totalCount = payload.total_count?.toInt() ?: 0
                            val listSize = teamsUiState.value.teamItems.size
                            teamsNextPageAvailable = (listSize >= totalCount).not()
                        }
                    }
                    is Result.Loading -> {
                        toggleTeamProgress(isRefresh)
                    }
                    is Result.Error -> {
                        _showToast.emit(
                            it.exception.message ?: getApplication<Application>().getString(
                                R.string.something_wrong_try_again
                            )
                        )
                        toggleTeamProgress(isRefresh)
                    }
                }
            }
```

And in the fragment I am observing it like this:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        teamsAdapter.submitList(it.teamItems)            
    }
}
```

Since I have pagination, I need to append the teams list to the already existing list.

The only way i could do this is by doing something like this:

```
_teamsUiState.update { teamsState ->
    val temp = ArrayList(teamsState.teamItems)
    temp.addAll(payload.teams)
    teamsState.copy(teamItems = temp)
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I want without using a `temp` variable?

Answer (score 3):

I guess there will be many ways to get this desired behaviour done, but a lot of boiler plate will come with as well, I think the best approach here would be to implement Paging 3 so you can handle pagination in a very easy and efficient way. Sources:

- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview

You can always have a look if you have doubts at a coding task project I made with this library:

- https://github.com/ManuelCrovetto/UserHub

Comment: I did come across this, and I am planning to move to this but at a later point of time. Is there any solution for my current issue? @MARCOSystems? Some way I could remove the temp variable? maybe with some terminal operators like ```fold``` or ```reduce```??

Comment: Hmm, got it, let me think… just to make sure, you are querying the backend also with a page number as query parameter?

Comment: yes @MACROSystems

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getAndUpdate {}` on `_teamsUiState`.

```
_teamsUiState.getAndUpdate { existingItems ->
    val newList = existingItems.teamItems.plus(newItems)
    TeamUiState(newList)
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how??
i tried ```getAndUpdate```

teamsState.copy() is still replacing the data now

Comment: I am assuming you meant like this ```_teamUiState.getAndUpdate { existingItems -> existingItems.teamItems.plus(newItems) existingItems }``` 
its not working. existingItems is of type ```TeamsUiState```

Comment: Nothing is getting emited so my observer is not getting anything

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the code to reflect your _teamsUiState class now.